# How to query WTPart by creator name?

Tags: ptc-windchill

Using the following code:

```
        QuerySpec qs = new QuerySpec(WTPart.class);
        qs.appendWhere(new SearchCondition(WTPart.class, WTPart.CREATOR_NAME, SearchCondition.EQUAL, name));
```

Got error

> Attribute "creator.name" is not attribute of class "wt.part.WTPart"

I also want to know how to query part by modifier name

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to query on modifier name

```
long userId=userName.getPersistInfo().getObjectIdentifier().getId();
QuerySpec qs = new QuerySpec(WTPart.class);
qs.appendWhere(new SearchCondition(WTPart.class,"iterationInfo.modifier.key.id",SearchCondition.EQUAL,userId), new int[] { 0, 1 });
```

I'm not sure about query on creator name, i'll check and update this

Comment: Thanks! Found solution,for creator it's "iterationInfo.creator.key.id"